# matplotlib PolygonSelector freezes when called in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm writing a script using tkinter and matplotlib for data processing, some parts of the code requires polygon selector to choose a region of interest. However, PolygonSelector fails to detect the motion of cursor.

***It should be noted that this issue occurs when the interactive mode of matplotlib figure is on.***

Simplified code and result are shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import PolygonSelector

root = tk.Tk()

def draw():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.ion()    # interactive mode is on
    plt.show()

    def onselect(data_input):
        print(data_input)

    PS = PolygonSelector(ax, onselect)

tk.Button(root, text='draw', command=draw).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This is the plot after clicking 'draw' button on tkinter GUI, the starting point of polygon stucks at (0,0), it is expected to move with cursor:

[image]

When I call `draw()` outside of tkinter, PolygonSelector works fine:

```
def draw():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.ion()    # interactive mode is on
    plt.show()

    def onselect(data_input):
        print(data_input)

    PS = PolygonSelector(ax, onselect)
    a = input()    # prevent window from closing when execution is done
draw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution would be to make sure you make your Polygon Selector a global variable. This will keep the selector visually updating.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import PolygonSelector
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


root = tk.Tk()
ps = None

def draw():
    global ps
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    ps = PolygonSelector(ax, on_select)


def on_select(data_input):
    print(data_input)

tk.Button(root, text='draw', command=draw).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If you build this into a class then you can avoid the use of global and get the behavior you want by apply the Polygon Selector as a class attribute.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import PolygonSelector
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ps = None
        tk.Button(self, text='draw', command=self.draw).pack()

    def draw(self):
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        plt.ion()
        plt.show()
        self.ps = PolygonSelector(ax, self.on_select)

    def on_select(self, data_input):
        print(data_input)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI().mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works! May I know why local variables don't work in this case?

Comment: Local variables only exist within the function they are created in. So when you do not define a variable as global or pass it to another looping function and the function has ended then the local variable is gone.